# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I have a problem with my POST. I'm trying to send a request with Postman [Postman screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC5bj.png) but I have an error in the terminal.
My code:

```
exports.createSauce = (req, res, next) => {  
  const sauce = new Sauce({ 
    ...req.body
  })
  sauce.save()
    .then(res.status(201).json({ message : "registered object !" }))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }))
}
```

My error message :

```
(node:2808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:481:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Workspace\P6_saumureau_thibaud\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Workspace\P6_saumureau_thibaud\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Workspace\P6_saumureau_thibaud\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at sauce.save.then.catch.error (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Workspace\P6_saumureau_thibaud\controllers\sauce.js:9:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
(node:2808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Someone have a solution ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post error messages and code as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `.then(res.status(201).json({ message : "registered object !" }))` calls `res.status(201).json({ message : "registered object !" })` imediatly and uses the result of that call as parameter passed to `then`.

So your `res.status(201).json({ message : "registered object !" })` will always be executed no matter if `save` was successful or not and will be called before the save happened.

According to the error message your save fails, so you first call `res.status(201).json({ message : "registered object !" })`  which sends header and body to the client, and then you call `res.status(400).json({ error })` which trys to send headers again, but the request was already send.

You have to convert the part in the `then` to a callback using e.g. an arrow function: `.then(() => res.status(201).json({ message : "registered object !" }))`

Comment: Thank you for your solution and your explanation ! Your advice works ! :)